# Error durante la lectura de datos desde un archivo a una estructura

Tags: c

Me encuentro recogiendo datos de un fichero, del fichero quiero coger el DNI y el nombre, y el error me lo da al intentar guardar los nombres en los distintos compartimentos usando `Nombre[i]`.

Codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100
int main(){
FILE *f1;
char Linea1[200],Linea2[200],Apellido[14],linea[40];
char Nombre[70];
int DNI[9];
int i=0;
f1=fopen("h.txt","r");
fgets(Linea1,200,f1);
fgets(Linea2,200,f1);
while(!feof(f1)){
        do{
                i=0;
   fscanf(f1,"%s %s %[^\n]",DNI[i],Nombre[i],linea);
   i++;
        }
        while(linea==NULL);

}

fclose(f1);

}
```

Les dejo también el fichero por si acaso les ayuda a localizar el error:

```
Fecha Examen: 2018/08/09
Numero de pruebas: 6
23321223D Markel Zubieta 4.47 3.06 5.09 5.11 8.18 7.95 6.44 3.79 8.12 5.33 2000/2/3
13080976G Antonio Gonzalez Perez 3.51 2.08 3.01 4.71 1943/12/21
34235676F Jose Luis Martinez Garcia 2.26 1.85 9.05 9.80 4.39 1986/2/29
X345432Y Victor Mayo 2.58 4.09 5.9 2.6 6.3 7.1 4.24 5.08 2000/11/12
20205632S Silva Martinez Fernandez 0.86 2.62 8.01 0.9 9.2 7 4.89 5.79 2.37 7 1970/04/10
```

Comment: Que error te da? y te das cuenta que con este codigo solo estas guardando los datos de la ultima fila, no?

Comment: En teoria , como he hecho con el DNI ,se me guarda con el bucle , por ejemplo si pongo que me imprima DNI[0] me saldra 23321223D , y eso me funciona , pero cuando lo hago con nombres se me crashea el programa

Comment: donde lo estas mostrando? y no es lo mismo. Un array de chars es como un string, no es un array de strings.. deberias revisar la documentacion de C sobre char...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El error es este:

```
fscanf(f1,"%s %s %[^\n]",DNI[i],Nombre[i],linea);
```

`DNI` está declarado como entero, pero lo estas leyendo como caracter. `Nombre` es un  arreglo de caracteres con capacidad para un solo nombre. Lo que tú quieres es poder almacenar varios `DNI` y `Nombres`. Para eso usare una estructura que los unifique, y cambiare el tipo de `DNI` a `char`:

```
#define MAX_ALUMNOS 30

struct {
    char Nombre[70];
    char DNI[10];
} curso[MAX_ALUMNOS];
```

Asi tengo un curso con alumnos, y cada alumno tiene un DNI de 9 caracters + '\0' y un nombre de 69 caracteres + '\0'.

Otro problema es que estas reiniciando el indice `'i'` en cada iteración. Cambiare esa variable por '`alumno`', ya que nombres significativos ayudan a la comprensión del código.

Con todo, queda así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ALUMNOS 100

int main() {
    FILE *f1;
    char Linea1[200], Linea2[200], Apellido[14], linea[40];
    struct {
        char Nombre[70];
        char DNI[10];
    } curso[MAX_ALUMNOS];
    
    f1 = fopen("h.txt", "r");
    fgets(Linea1, 200, f1);
    fgets(Linea2, 200, f1);

    int alumno = 0;
    while (!feof(f1)) {
       fscanf(f1, "%s %s %[^\n]", curso[alumno].DNI, curso[alumno].Nombre, linea);
       alumno++;
    }
    fclose(f1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= alumno; i++) {
        printf("%d %s %s\n", i, curso[i].DNI, curso[i].Nombre);
    }
}
```

Nota: no hay manejo de errores.

**Demostración**

Con el archivo proporcionado, la ejecución produce:

```
0 23321223D Markel
1 13080976G Antonio
2 34235676F Jose
3 X345432Y Victor
4 20205632S Silva
```

Sólo se leyó el primer nombre, pues eso es lo que hace scanf cuando encuentra "%s" ... leer hasta el primer espacio.